# Modify Function Output - Inspect Source - Javascript- HTML - Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, dom, google-chrome-devtools

I want to modify the output of the functions (just say RANDOM examples, apologies for any code mistakes):

```
ng-if=!pfile.isgame
ng-if=! pfile.examplefile
```

-from false to true before it even has the page has any chance to drop any code on the page. How can I make it so I can append code to the page to the very beginning of the page to force every output of these particular functions to go true,  on a live page?

This is definitely possible, I'm not sure where the function would be however the elements you can actually see the arguments on the page and it doesn't not look server sided at all, its just how its done. I read many articles but it many of them have not really helped me.

I am aware of Event Listener Breakpoints, its just the problem if I'm choosing the right one.

Thank you and I really appreciate it just if you can please dum down the explanation for me as even though I do understand HTML and JavaScript to an OK standard, I am still a massive beginner. This is something I always wanted to try out.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I have understood your question correctly. There are a couple of options and the answer will depend on whether the functions are declarations or expressions.

If they are declarations, they get hoisted to the top on first pass, so that by the time your code begins execution, the function already exists and you can overwrite it early on.

If it's a function expression, you have to wait until the function expression has been created.

**Example 1 (Function Declaration):**

I have a function declaration on my page, which returns `true` if there is a remainder in the calculation, otherwise `false`. I execute it on page load. The output is `false` here:

```
function hasRemainder(first, second) {
    return (first % second != 0);
}

console.log(hasRemainder(10, 5));
```

> false

I have now added the `Script First Statement` breakpoint in DevTools, so that the debugger breaks before any script is run:

[image: Script First Statement]

I re-open the page and the execution pauses. I now run the following code in the Console tab to override the `hasRemainder` function so that it always returns `true`:

```
hasRemainder = function() {
    return true;
}
```

Finally, I click Play to continue execution. You can long click to select Long Resume, which skips breakpoints for 500ms so that you don't get caught for very single breakpoint thereafter.

> true

The output this time is `true` as you would expect.

**Example 2 (Function Expression):**

We can't rely on the early breakpoint this time because the function won't exist yet. We need to add the breakpoint just after the function expression has been created.

Search for the functions using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Windows).

[image: Search]

When you are in the file with the function expression, put a breakpoint at the end of the function. When the debugger pauses, run the overriding function into the Console, and then press play to continue execution.

[image: Function Expression]